# Looking for MRI file repository for Finite Element Modeling of ACL

Tags: mri, medical-imaging, acl-ligament

Does anyone know of any online/open access MRI image collections? I am looking for 3D geometry for an ACL to mesh and model for a Finite Element Modeling course, and I'm having trouble locating source files. We have a CT scan, but the resolution is too low for the application.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: bings got loads: https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=mri+images&qpvt=mri+images&FORM=IGRE

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I would imagine that if a CT source file is not of sufficient resolution, that a 2d representation of a 3d image saved as a JPG or TIFF file won't be sufficient either.

Comment: @JohnP is right. I am looking for DICOM files or similar file types. I've found a sample on the DICOM library  [link] (https://www.dicomlibrary.com/meddream/md5/?study=1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.1055.1.20111103111148288.98361414.79379639) website that is the type of image that we want, but the resolution of the ACL is actually worse than our CT scan. I'm currently looking at the fully sampled knees on mridata.org. I'll post it back here if I find anything.